# 95% CI interpretation on transformed data using (abs(x-mean(x)))

Tags: r, confidence-interval, data-transformation, lm, back-transformation

I have a problem for which no search has provided an answer.

I am using `lm()` to build a model which I tested to ensure it met all assumptions using the following

```
mod1<-lm(y~x1+x2,
        data=mydata, na.action=na.exclude)


gvlma::gvlma(mod1)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x1 + x2, data = mydata, na.action = na.exclude)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         x1         x2  
    0.11508      0.01658      0.65672  


ASSESSMENT OF THE LINEAR MODEL ASSUMPTIONS
USING THE GLOBAL TEST ON 4 DEGREES-OF-FREEDOM:
Level of Significance =  0.05 

Call:
 gvlma::gvlma(x = mod1) 

                      Value   p-value                   Decision
Global Stat        35.10643 4.417e-07 Assumptions NOT satisfied!
Skewness           13.97982 1.848e-04 Assumptions NOT satisfied!
Kurtosis           10.86129 9.820e-04 Assumptions NOT satisfied!
Link Function       0.04772 8.271e-01    Assumptions acceptable.
Heteroscedasticity 10.21760 1.391e-03 Assumptions NOT satisfied!
```

I added the following transformation which fixed the problem

```
mod2<-lm(abs(y-mean(y))~x1+x2,
       data=mp2017.dat, na.action=na.exclude)

gvlma::gvlma(mod2)

Call:
lm(formula = abs(y - mean(y)) ~ x1 +x2, data = mydata, 
    na.action = na.exclude)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         x1         x2  
   0.506339    -0.009096    -0.084931  


ASSESSMENT OF THE LINEAR MODEL ASSUMPTIONS
USING THE GLOBAL TEST ON 4 DEGREES-OF-FREEDOM:
Level of Significance =  0.05 

Call:
 gvlma::gvlma(x = mod2) 

                    Value p-value                Decision
Global Stat        3.5881  0.4646 Assumptions acceptable.
Skewness           0.3330  0.5639 Assumptions acceptable.
Kurtosis           1.9471  0.1629 Assumptions acceptable.
Link Function      0.3135  0.5755 Assumptions acceptable.
Heteroscedasticity 0.9945  0.3186 Assumptions acceptable.
```

I am now trying to interpret point estimate and 95% CI but I am not sure how to do this as they relate to the transformed data. Should I attempt to back transform the CI? If so, how should I do this? Or, if this is not possible, how can I make sense of the CIs?

Many thanks

Comment: Back-transforming makes no sense here. You threw away the sign, so the transformation is not reversible. It's not like the logarithm or any other one-to-one transformation for which there is a unique inverse. Either your response is on an interesting and useful scale in which case there is no need to transform; or it's impossible. I am really surprised at the idea that this transformation would improve anything for a linear model. Can you post the data or tell us a public source for `mp2017.dat`?

Comment: My apologies @NickCox mp2017.dat just refers to my data which I am using but I am unable to share it. I have edited my question and I have also added the script to show why I transformed the data and that it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show e.g. a histogram of `y` and of `abs(y - mean(y)) to make clear what this transformation is doing? Or equivalently show a fake data set with the same behaviour? Either way, there isn't a back-transformation that you can use here.

Comment: I don't know what `gvlma` does precisely but it's a general fact that the normality assumption in linear model at most applies to the stochastic errors. It's the least important assumption in my experience!